# Pyplot 1D heatmap problems

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a CSV file full with data which are ints (positive and negative) and wanted to create a 1D Heatmap (or a Heatbar, if that exists).

Here is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib as mat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as np

import csv

a=([0,0])

a = np.resize(a,(1,96)) #the are 96 numbers from -56 to 40

with open('Start_0.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
     k = np.array(list(reader)) #read every row in the CSV
     k = k.reshape((-1,7)) #every row has 7 data cells
     for row in k:
    
    i = int(row[4])                  #i only need the fourth cell
    if (i < 45)&(i > -50):           #if the number is between 45 and -50...
        a[0][i+50] = a[0][i+50] + 1  #increase the corresponding position by 1
print (a)

norm = mat.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
plot.imshow(a, aspect = "auto", cmap="viridis", interpolation = "nearest")
plot.show()
```

My data are numbers from a high negative number to a high positiv number, but only numbers between -50 and 46 are interesting. Thats why i add 50 to every number i pick to fit in the array. With that i create a custom histogram of my data.

and here is the result:
[image]

Since I have to do the workaround of adding 50 to every array position, my 0 indices is not at the right position. But neither numpy.histogram, nor numpy.histogram2d is working. numpy.histogram gives me a real histogram, not a heapmap, and histogram2d is not the right format and I don't know how to bring it in the right shape.

How can i manually set my indices to the right position or change my array to get the right indice position?

Comment: There is no way of knowing your data, so the issue of "adding 50" is unclear. It is also unclear what "my 0 indices are not right" means. It is at least not a clear problem description. It is also not clear why you are looking at histograms, since it seems that you already have the data to plot available. You are probably correct in saying that a 2D histogram is not useful for 1D data. Second, mind that you should ask one question per question, if you have two questions ask two questions. There are enough resources that tell you how to change the size of a figure or axes.

Comment: So in conclusion Question 1 is not answerable, since the plot seams to be ok and the problem description is missing. Question 2 can be solved easily by using the search engine of choice.

Comment: First of all thank you for the comments, i changed my question to make it more clear and just ask one question.

Comment: Still unclear, sorry. Can't you just hard-code 10 values that mimic your case and clearly state the problem: What is wrong with the plot that's produced? How should is look instead? Be specific, like "I want the ticklabel at position 5 to that the value x", such that people would understand the issue?

Comment: But thats what i said: the indice for 0 ( or the label or whatever) is not at the zero point, cause the position 0 in my array is the the number of appearances of -50 in my data. So, the position 50 in my array is the number of appearances of my number 0 in my data, I hope i got it clearer now.

Comment: Well, you did not say that. Now it's clear and I can provide an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data range of an image can be set via the `extent` keyword argument to `imshow`. This sets the range with a tuple `(left, right, bottom, top)`.
Using the minimum and maximum bin edges of the histogram for the extent allow to shift the data to their original values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 5,2

pos = np.arange(-56,40) #there are 96 numbers from -56 to 39
print len(pos), pos.min(), pos.max()
p = np.random.rand(len(pos))
p= p/np.sum(p)

a= np.random.choice(pos, size=4000, p=p) 
# now a contains 4000 numbers between -56 and 39

bins=np.arange(-56,41) #there are 96 bins, hence 97 edges from -56 to 40
hist, edges = np.histogram(a, bins)
hist=hist[np.newaxis,:]

extent=[bins.min(), bins.max(),0,1]
plt.imshow(hist, aspect = "auto", cmap="viridis", extent=extent)
plt.gca().set_yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]